# Missing right parenthesis Oracle Issue

Tags: sql

I 'm using Oracle Application Express Edition 4.0.2.00.09
While creating the table I'm getting error "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis", I have checked previously asked question on this however could not make it through.

```
Create table NewOne (

PersonId Int(10),

Hire_Date varchar(255),
Tenure number(255),
Review varchar(255),
Next_Day varchar(255),
Last_day varchar(255)

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the changes below

1. Change int to number
2. Change number(255) to number(38) , as 38 is the max allowed for number

It should work fine.

Check out the db fiddle link - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d1fecc3e55708115d2326fdeec34243d

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify a length for the INT subtype, it is what it is. You should use the NUMBER type instead.

Once you fix that you'll find that your tenure column is specified with 255 digits, I don't think that's close to reality and will also error.

You should be using VARCHAR2 not VARCHAR on Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

`int` is a perfectly acceptable Oracle type.  However, `int(10)` is not.  `Number` itself is limited to a max of 38.  And Oracle recommend `varchar2()` instead of `varchar()`.  So I would recommend:

```
Create table NewOne (
    PersonId Int,
    Hire_Date varchar2(255),
    Tenure number,
    Review varchar2(255),
    Next_Day varchar2(255),
    Last_day varchar2(255)
);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c1e70b17f11675761b81418141b89431) is a db<>fiddle